# MVC - Some properties taken in PHP are not accessible with Javascript

Tags: javascript, php, model-view-controller, laravel-5, vue.js

I'm developing an online store with Laravel (MVC framework for PHP) and Vue.js, but I think I would have the same problem with other technologies.

My Products table on database has some params such as the id, name, description... and the urls to images are stored in other table of the database. A product have many images and an image belongs to one product.

If I take a product from de database, it is easy and works fine. This is the ProductController (Laravel code) and works fine:

```
$products = $categories->find($categoryId)->products()->get();
Product::setMainThumbnailForCollection($products);
dd($products); //dd = die dump => var_dump + die
```

I take a collection of items which is an array with all the products. DB attributes are inside and array called attributes and the thumbnail URL it's outside that array. Remember, the imageUrl comes from another DB:

[image: Result for die dump. A collection of Products with imageUrl outside de attributes array.]

I set the imageUrl inside my Product model, and works fine:

```
foreach($products as $product){
    $product->mainThumbnail = $this->getAndSetMainThumbnail($product); 
}
```

I send the product collection to de view and here is when I use vue.js. So I can access with Javascript to the products but ONLY to those attibutes which where inside the attributes array I explained before:

```
<!-- send products to template this is stil php -->
<products list="{{ json_encode($products) }}"></products>

<template id="products-template">
    <!-- here we're using now javascript -->

    <div v-for="product in list">
        <!-- vue.js for loop. I can't access to the thumbnail URL I take from the other database -->
        @{{ product.id }} //WORKS: I have access
        @{{ product.mainThumbnail }} //DOESN'T WORK: I have no access to this property
        <!-- rest of the code -->
        <!-- ... -->
```

I think should be a way to attach the image URL to the attributes in the ProductController but I have not found the way to do.

Comment: Try declaring a `public $mainThumbnail` property in your Product model

Comment: Yeah Damien, it's done. In the image could see has the + sign (very little), so it's declared as public

Comment: Damien, you gave me the clue! I've declared that property as public in the Controller, not in the View